# Moving folder contents up 2 directory levels

Tags: linux, permissions, mv, directory-structure

I'm trying to write a command that uses `mv` to move files two directory levels up.

So if the folder order goes like this: `~/Test/2020-08-01/001/002/file.txt`, I want to move `file.txt` from directory `002` to directory `2020-08-01`.

When I type out this command from my home directory `mv ~/Test/2020-08-01/001/002/* ../..` I get an error that says: `mv: cannot move '/home/user/Test/2020-08-01/001/002/file1.txt' to '../../file1.txt': Permission denied`

I don't understand why I'm getting a "Permission denied" error and I don't think it's sudo-related. I also don't want to try sudo in case I mess something up.

If anyone has any insight please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: In your case `../..` actually points to `/` (try running: `realpath ../..`) and for that reason you get **Permission denied**. The command should be: `mv ~/Test/2020-08-01/001/002/* ~/Test/2020-08-01`

Comment: Maybe show the output of `ls -ld ../..`, or change your directory to `~/Test/2020-08-01/001/002` before running the command `mv * ../..`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `../..` in your command is relative to your *current* directory.  If your current directory is `/home/user`, then `../..` refers to the root of the directory hierarchy (where your non-privileged user can't write).

To move `file.txt` from `~/Test/2020-08-01/001/002` to `~/Test/2020-08-01`, use

```bash
mv ~/Test/2020-08-01/001/002/file.txt ~/Test/2020-08-01
```

If you want to use relative directory paths, then ensure that you are first in the correct directory, then perform the move:

```bash
cd ~/Test/2020-08-01/001/002
mv file.txt ../..
```

or,

```bash
cd ~/Test/2020-08-01
mv 001/002/file.txt .
```

... or some combination thereof.